# folding@home: How to drop a stuck work unit?

Tags: 20.04, foldingathome

My FAH system is running properly most of the time.

- FAHControl -> About: Version 7.6.13
- `FAHClient --version` -> 7.6.13
- `grep DESC /etc/*release` -> "Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"

I am using CPU processing only (i.e. no GPU).

FAHControl shows the following:
[image: FAHControl showing two work units]

- Work unit 00 is currently work in progress.
- Work unit 02 is dead.
- I want to drop/remove/purge/flush/dump work unit 02.

I tried the following:

- add a new folding slot
- delete the current slot
- similar things in different permutations

However, always new WU are being downloaded and processed, and if no slot is there, the WU just waits, so does the dead one.

I also tried from Shell:

```
{17:23}/var/lib/fahclient/work ➭ FAHClient --dump 02            
16:29:39:Trying to access database...
16:29:39:Successfully acquired database lock
16:29:39:Downloading GPUs.txt from assign1.foldingathome.org:80
16:29:39:Connecting to assign1.foldingathome.org:80
16:29:40:Read GPUs.txt
16:29:40:Enabled folding slot 00: PAUSED cpu:22 (not configured)
16:29:40:Enabled folding slot 01: PAUSED gpu:0:TU116 [GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER] (not configured)
16:29:40:ERROR:Exception: Could not bind socket to 0.0.0.0:7396: Address already in use
16:29:40:ERROR:Exception: Could not bind socket to 0.0.0.0:36330: Address already in use
16:29:40:****************************** FAHClient ******************************
16:29:40:        Version: 7.6.13
16:29:40:         Author: Joseph Coffland <joseph@cauldrondevelopment.com>
16:29:40:      Copyright: 2020 foldingathome.org
16:29:40:       Homepage: https://foldingathome.org/
16:29:40:           Date: Apr 28 2020
16:29:40:           Time: 04:20:16
16:29:40:       Revision: 5a652817f46116b6e135503af97f18e094414e3b
16:29:40:         Branch: master
16:29:40:       Compiler: GNU 8.3.0
16:29:40:        Options: -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O3
16:29:40:                 -funroll-loops -fno-pie
16:29:40:       Platform: linux2 4.19.0-5-amd64
16:29:40:           Bits: 64
16:29:40:           Mode: Release
16:29:40:           Args: --dump 02
16:29:40:******************************** CBang ********************************
16:29:40:           Date: Apr 25 2020
16:29:40:           Time: 00:07:53
16:29:40:       Revision: ea081a3b3b0f4a37c4d0440b4f1bc184197c7797
16:29:40:         Branch: master
16:29:40:       Compiler: GNU 8.3.0
16:29:40:        Options: -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O3
16:29:40:                 -funroll-loops -fno-pie -fPIC
16:29:40:       Platform: linux2 4.19.0-5-amd64
16:29:40:           Bits: 64
16:29:40:           Mode: Release
16:29:40:******************************* System ********************************
16:29:40:            CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor
16:29:40:         CPU ID: AuthenticAMD Family 23 Model 113 Stepping 0
16:29:40:           CPUs: 24
16:29:40:         Memory: 31.34GiB
16:29:40:    Free Memory: 17.53GiB
16:29:40:        Threads: POSIX_THREADS
16:29:40:     OS Version: 5.4
16:29:40:    Has Battery: false
16:29:40:     On Battery: false
16:29:40:     UTC Offset: 1
16:29:40:            PID: 185503
16:29:40:            CWD: /var/lib/fahclient/work
16:29:40:             OS: Linux 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64
16:29:40:        OS Arch: AMD64
16:29:40:           GPUs: 1
16:29:40:          GPU 0: Bus:10 Slot:0 Func:0 NVIDIA:7 TU116 [GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER]
16:29:40:  CUDA Device 0: Platform:0 Device:0 Bus:10 Slot:0 Compute:7.5 Driver:11.0
16:29:40:OpenCL Device 0: Platform:0 Device:0 Bus:10 Slot:0 Compute:1.2 Driver:450.80
16:29:40:******************************* libFAH ********************************
16:29:40:           Date: Apr 15 2020
16:29:40:           Time: 21:43:24
16:29:40:       Revision: 216968bc7025029c841ed6e36e81a03a316890d3
16:29:40:         Branch: master
16:29:40:       Compiler: GNU 8.3.0
16:29:40:        Options: -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O3
16:29:40:                 -funroll-loops -fno-pie
16:29:40:       Platform: linux2 4.19.0-5-amd64
16:29:40:           Bits: 64
16:29:40:           Mode: Release
16:29:40:***********************************************************************
16:29:40:<config>
16:29:40:  <!-- Folding Slots -->
16:29:40:  <slot id='0' type='CPU'/>
16:29:40:  <slot id='1' type='GPU'/>
16:29:40:</config>
16:29:40:Unit processing completed
16:29:40:Saving configuration to config.xml
16:29:40:<config>
16:29:40:  <!-- Folding Slots -->
16:29:40:  <slot id='0' type='CPU'/>
16:29:40:  <slot id='1' type='GPU'/>
16:29:40:</config>
16:29:40:Set client configured
16:29:40:Clean exit
```

It seems that running FAHClient it somehow creates a new FAH process/server instead of using the existing one. Also, using other command line options, the invoked FAHClient starts downloading and folding new work units (confusingly, also named 00 etc.).

So the question seems to be how can I make FAHClient use the existing FAH process?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: It is 20.04, I added this info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stop FAHClient process, and cd to `/var/lib/fahclient` before dumping.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give a more general answer (regardless of the O/S).

Look at the log, specifically the line:

```
16:29:40:            CWD: /var/lib/fahclient/work
```

There is your client's *Current Working Directory*. Check your bad Work Unit's ID (00, 01, 02, …). Close the client. Browse to the CWD and in the directory "work" and you should see directories named (00, 01, 02, …) – one directory per each Work Unit. Remove the bad one. Done. You can start your client now, it'll clean itself up.